# Making delete, update, insert and get operations nested json data structure on dynamodb

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

My data structure is like below:
[image]

I want update,delete a room in the rooms list with roomId. Should i add a secondary index to roomId? How should be update and delete queries ? Also i want to get room informations with roomId.

For remove a room, can the code structure be like that:

```
  const roomItem = {
    TableName: 'Home',
    Key: {
      homeId: homeId
    },
    IndexName: 'roomId-index',
    ConditionExpression: 'rooms.roomId = :roomId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':roomId': roomId
    }
  };
  await dynamodb.delete(roomItem).promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a Secondary Index on a non top-level Attribute**

You cannot create a `Secondary Index` on `rooms.roomId` where it is a nested attribute

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

> Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute
> of type String, Number, or Binary.

--

To be able to retrieve by `roomId`, you have the options of either:

- Use `Scan`, or
- Re-design your schema to make `roomId` a / part of a Table's `Key` in a new `Table` so that you can use achieve milliseconds `Query` retrieval

Example

```
Hash Key (House Id)  | Range Key (Room Id)
---------------------+---------------------
55555555             | 1
---------------------+---------------------
55555555             | 2
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but what do you mean saying scan ?